# CreateObject error: "Only one version of Outlook can run at a time." in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have lines of code which worked for a year but not for the last 10 days.

If I try to create a new Outlook object this message appears:

[image]

```
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim OutlookMail As Object

Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutlookMail
    .To = mail@mail.com
    .Subject = "Subject"
    .HTMLBody = "Body"
    .Display
End With
```

The error appears when I try to create an instance of Outlook:

```
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

I run the Outlook app as Administrator.

I tried to create email another way but with no success:

```
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim OutlookMail As Object

On Error Resume Next
   Set OutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If OutlookApp Is Nothing Then
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If

Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0) ' 0 represents olMailItem
```

Comment: What error do you get with the second way? - Maybe you shouldn't just be ignoring the error? "no success" does not explain anything at all

Comment: That link is not working for me - what does the error say.
Have you tried using Early Binding instead?
Have you googled e.g. https://www.devhut.net/createobjectoutlook-application-does-not-work-now-what/

Answer (score 0):

Your error doesn't say it cannot start Outlook because it's already running, it says that it cannot start a different version. Now that's a little bit misleading: It cannot start Outlook because there is one running already *in a different context* (with administrator privileges).

It's only an educated guess, but I assume that Outlook opens resources (eg files), and it cannot share those resources on multiple instances running different privileges.

If you look to to the task manager: If you start Outlook "normal" and execute `CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`, no new Outlook task is visible. I assume that the instance already running is returned. However, an instance running with different privileges cannot be returned, else the calling code (in your case Excel) would gain admin privileges. That's the case also for your second attempt using `GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")`.

A workaround would be to run Excel also as Administrator. But from security aspects, executing VBA code as Administrator sounds like a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook is a singleton, so when `Outlook.Application` object is created, the new instance of outlook.exe checks if another instance is running and transfers control to it. If the first instance hanged or is running in a different security context (e.g. either one is running as administrator and another as a regular user), you have a problem.

If you run into this error, open Task Manager, check if outlook.exe is running, right click, "End task".